# commutative diagram for compositions using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, commutative-diagrams

so i tried to do this commutative diagram using tikz. However, no success. I tried using google and reading manuals but unfortunately, i either didnt understand the syntax or it didnt fit my needs.
i really could use some help. the diagram itself is pretty basic. i would really a ppreciate it if someone could either help me drawing it or point me towards a good tutorial/manual where i can learn from.

this is the diagram i was trying to do:

[image]

thank you very much

Comment: You might want to try this: http://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de/#eyJub2RlcyI6W3sicG9zaXRpb24iOlswLDBdLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IkEifSx7InBvc2l0aW9uIjpbMSwwXSwidmFsdWUiOiJCIn0seyJwb3NpdGlvbiI6WzIsMF0sInZhbHVlIjoiQyJ9LHsicG9zaXRpb24iOlszLDBdLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IkQifV0sImVkZ2VzIjpbeyJmcm9tIjowLCJ0byI6MX0seyJmcm9tIjoxLCJ0byI6Mn0seyJmcm9tIjoyLCJ0byI6M30seyJmcm9tIjowLCJ0byI6MiwiYmVuZCI6LTMwLCJ2YWx1ZSI6ImcgXFxjaXJjIGYiLCJsYWJlbFBvc2l0aW9uIjoicmlnaHQifSx7ImZyb20iOjEsInRvIjozLCJiZW5kIjozMCwidmFsdWUiOiJoIFxcY2lyYyBnIn1dfQ== Click the `{}` button to copy the code.

Comment: @HenriMenke thank you very much! this was exactly what i was looking for.